# How to execute exit processing when my non-form application is closing

Tags: c#, .net, process, task

I am writing the application about a global hook with C#(.NET 4.0) and C++.

Hooking of 32 bit application cannot be received on 64 bit. So I launches 32 bits applications(Hooker.exe) as an other process and communicate with a main application.

At the time of an application is closed, it must release a created hook. But, the process of Hooker.exe is not finished by this program. Even so, if Process.Kill() is used, it will not execute release processing.

Main.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    Process p = Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + "Hooker.exe");
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
    p.Close();
}
```

Hooker.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    // call hook function from C++ DLL
    Debug.WriteLine("start hook");

    Application.Run();

    // call unhook function from C++ DLL
    Debug.WriteLine("release hook");
}
```

Is there any good way of solving these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct way. I would suggest to monitor your process in a thread: Get list of processes in a loop and  check if your process is running. If not, then release hook.

Or, use cross-processing communication, as described [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_CrossProcess_EventWaitHandle)

Comment: It's a great reverse thinking!